# Isn't it ok in terms of memory leakage etc

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks, dynamic-memory-allocation

It's been about 2 months since I started to learn c++ and I'm not quite sure about I'm doing wrong for my project. I have a dynamically allocated array with an initial size and after I want to change the size of it. The thing I wonder is why the following code is **wrong**

```
    int *firstPtr = new int [4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        firstPtr[i] = i;
    }

    int *tempPtr = new int[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        tempPtr[i] = firstPtr[i];
    }
    tempPtr[4] = 4;
   // firstPtr = new int[5];
    firstPtr = tempPtr;
    delete tempPtr;

     for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cout << firstPtr[i] << endl;
    }
```

---

because the output is:

*10757752 

10753936 

2 

3 

4*

---

**PS:** I can't use realloc/malloc etc for this since the project is just about pointers. How can I correct this without them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
firstPtr = tempPtr;
```

first Ptr now points to the same memory as tempPtr.

```
delete tempPtr;
```

You are now deleting that memory, the same memory both firstPtr and tempPtr are pointing to.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    cout << firstPtr[i] << endl;
}
```

You are accessing deleted memory, the values printed can be anything.

To get what I'm assuming you want, you need to remove the line

```
firstPtr = tempPtr;
```

or delete the memory after the for:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    cout << firstPtr[i] << endl;
}
delete[] tempPtr;
```

Note that in the second case you will get a memory leak, since the memory initially pointed to by `firstPtr` is no longer accessible.

**A complete working and correct code would be as follows:**

```
int *firstPtr = new int [4];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    firstPtr[i] = i;
}

int *tempPtr = new int[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    tempPtr[i] = firstPtr[i];
}
tempPtr[4] = 4;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    cout << firstPtr[i] << endl;
}
delete[] tempPtr;
delete[] firstPtr;
```

**Some ASCII art:**

```
firstPtr = new int[4];

firstPtr
   |
+------++------++------++------+
|      ||      ||      ||      |
|      ||      ||      ||      |
+------++------++------++------+

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    firstPtr[i] = i;
}

firstPtr
   |
+------++------++------++------+
|   0  ||   1  ||   2  ||   3  |
|      ||      ||      ||      |
+------++------++------++------+

int *tempPtr = new int[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        tempPtr[i] = firstPtr[i];
    }
    tempPtr[4] = 4;

tempPtr
   |
+------++------++------++------++------+
|   0  ||   1  ||   2  ||   3  ||   4  |
|      ||      ||      ||      ||      |
+------++------++------++------++------+
```

So now, in memory, you have:

```
firstPtr
   |
+------++------++------++------+
|   0  ||   1  ||   2  ||   3  |
|      ||      ||      ||      |
+------++------++------++------+

tempPtr
   |
+------++------++------++------++------+
|   0  ||   1  ||   2  ||   3  ||   4  |
|      ||      ||      ||      ||      |
+------++------++------++------++------+
```

Your next line:

```
firstPtr = tempPtr;
```

does this:

```
no longer pointed to by firstPtr
   |
+------++------++------++------+
|   0  ||   1  ||   2  ||   3  |
|      ||      ||      ||      |
+------++------++------++------+

tempPtr
firstPtr  -  firstPtr now points here
   |
+------++------++------++------++------+
|   0  ||   1  ||   2  ||   3  ||   4  |
|      ||      ||      ||      ||      |
+------++------++------++------++------+

delete tempPtr;

tempPtr
firstPtr  -  firstPtr now points here
   |
+------++------++------++------++------+
|   x  ||   x  ||   x  ||   x  ||   x  |
|      ||      ||      ||      ||      |
+------++------++------++------++------+
```

So now, tempPtr points to delete memory. Hope this clears things up.

Comment: After I increased the size of firstPtr, I don't need tempPtr because my work is done with it. Why can't I just delete the pointer tempPtr?

Comment: @CihadTurhan, you can, just don't make firstPtr point to the same location.

Comment: As far as I understand, I should keep both pointers because when I delete one of them, the memory is deallocated which means both pointers will point to irrelevant addresses. Is that true?

Comment: @CihadTurhan I edited my answer, hope it makes things clearer. A pointer is just a variable that contains a memory address. With, firstPtr = tempPtr, both are pointing to the same address, which you then delete, so both will point to deleted memory.

Comment: @Cihad: no, you need to keep both pointers only in case you'd do `firstPtr = tempPtr;` as they'd point to the same memory region.

Comment: Very nice drawing, for the complete solution I would have recommended the usage of `std::vector<int>` though.

Comment: @MatthieuM., agreed, I was too busy making ASCII, I forgot about std::vector :)

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Thanks so much. Your drawing are very explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

1. by assigning to `firstPtr` to will be unable to free memory behind the overwritten pointer
2. deleting `tempPtr` you make data pointed to by `firstPtr` invalidated (the immedaite cause of wrong output)

Solution:

1. add line to delete `firstPtr` before assignment line "firstPtr = tempPtr;"
2. move line that deletes `tempPtr` below "cout <<" loop

Answer (score 1):

It's here

```
firstPtr = tempPtr;
delete tempPtr;
```

you see, you assign the value of `tempPtr` to `firstPtr`, which means that they're referring to the same memory location (at this point you have no pointer to the old memory, which used to be pointed to by `firstPtr`), then you deallocate (`delete`) the memory pointed-to by `tempPtr`, which is the same memory actually.

The correct way should be

```
delete firstPtr;
firstPtr = tempPtr;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
 firstPtr = tempPtr;
 delete tempPtr;
```

You need

```
 delete [] firstPtr;
 firstPtr = tempPtr;
```

And later, after you're done, don't forget

```
 delete [] firstPtr;
```

In your original post you first have your firstPtr point at the newly allocated memore, then free it. So both firstPtr and tmpPrt point at freed memory. Using freed memory is Undefined Behavior. Also, please consider using `std::vector<int>`s. That will make your life easier.

Comment: Should be `delete[]`, not `delete`

Answer (score 0):

```
firstPtr = tempPtr;
delete tempPtr;
```

Then you use `firstPtr` but it is the same as `tempPtr` which is a pointer that you deleted.

Try drawing on paper what is happenning inside your heap to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You're accessing deleted memory. This is undefined behavior.

This is similar to reading a value from a `malloc()`ed pointer after `free()` has been called.